# A reducibility of $x^{14}+1$ in the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Find the smallest field $F$, which has characteristic $2$, where the polynomial $x^{14}+1$ decomposes into linear factors.

I've tried to decompose it (to be honest, to guess the decomposition) in some fields (2, 4, 8) - but I've no idea how to find roots. Should I guess only 1 root $x_0$ - and after divide $x^{14}+1$ by $x-x_0$ modulo $2$? And continiue until i find all roots?

Comment: A number will be a root if, when you sub it into the equation, you get zero. You can use modular congruence rules to figure out what value(s) to the fourteenth power are equivalent to $-1$ mod the order of the field.

Comment: $x^{14}+1=(x^7-1)^2$ in characteristic 2. Moreover $7=2^3-1$...

Comment: The non-zero elements of a field $F$ with $n+1$ elements form a multiplicative group of order $n$ and satisfy $x^n=1$. Since a polynomial of degree $n$ over a field can have at most $n$ roots, the non-zero elements of the field are distinct roots of $p(x)=x^n-1$ which therefore splits into $n$ linear factors over $F$.

Comment: @Roland, thanks! From this I understood that $(x^7-1)^2$ has roots when $7 | 2^n-1$. But reducibility does not mean the presence of roots. So my steps are to prove that  $(x^7-1)^2$ doesn't decompose into linear factors in $F_2$ and $F_4$ (How can I do it?) and after find the decomposition in $F_8$ - right?

Comment: You want to prove that $(x^7-1)^2$ is irreducible ? It isn't : it is a square. The question was in which fields $x^{14}+1$ splits into linear factors. Now, $x^7-1$ has no multiple roots (compute its derivative), so it can't be completely split in $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_4$. On the other hand, it is completely split in $\mathbb{F}_8$.

Comment: @Roland, thanks, everything is clear except the fact that $x^7-1$ has no multiple roots. You suggested computing its derivative. How could it help? $(x^7-1)'=7x^6=x^6$. As I know, polynomial $f$ has multiple root $a$ iff $f'(a)=0$. But in $F_2$ and $F_4$: $x^3=1$ for each nonzero element $=> x^6=1$ for each nonzero element $=> x^6=0$ has only 0 solution - thus $x^7-1$ has no multiple roots except 0 - but 0 isn't solution. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, the only zero of $f'(x)=7x^6=x^6$ is $0$ which is not a zero of $f(x)=x^7-1$, so $f$ has no multiple roots. In fact, in $\mathbb{F}_8$, every non zero element is satisfy $x^7-1=0$ (this is because the multiplicative group is of order 7), so you have 7 distinct roots for $x^7-1$. As a conclusion in $\mathbb{F}_8, x^7-1$ splits as $\prod_{a\in\mathbb{F}_8^*}(x-a)$.